# ubundu 16.04 sound panel always muted

Tags: 16.04, sound, volume-control

I have just move `/home` folder from SSD  to HDD and now sound panel is always in muted state. When I pick **Sound settings**, I cannot see any sound devices in **play sound through** box and volume cannot be changed through **Output volume** slider. The only way to handle volume is by using `alsamixer` utility. Sound is working perfectly otherwise.

Comment: Just a hunch but does it help if you move the per-user PulseAudio configuration out of the way (e. g. `mv ~/.pulse ~/pulse.bak`) and restart PulseAudio (`pulseudio -k; pulseaudio --start`)?

Answer (score 0):

After you set up your sound by opening alsamixer manually, input

```bsh
sudo alsactl store
```

in the terminal and it should save your sound levels.